# Correlate two binary data in python

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, coefficients

I want to correlate two binary data in python.
For eg, below are two arrays.

```
arr1 = [0,1,0,1,1,1,1]
arr2 = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I want to know the correlation coefficient of these two data.

I know that continuous and continuous variables use **pearson or Kendall's method**.

In the case of binary type and continuous type, you can use **Point biserial correlation coefficient** method.

The above methods are in python's scipy.

But I don't know how to measure the correlation coefficient between binary type and binary type.

Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It's not homework. But I am doing correlations with the data.

Answer (score -1):

This link gives you some advice for calculating the correlation of binary variables.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103801/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-pearson-or-spearman-correlation-between-two-boolea

Quote from origin answer: 
Pearson or Kendall's may not good similarity metrics for two binary vectors. You can use

- Jaccard-Needham
- Dice
- Yule
- Russell-Rao
- Sokal-Michener
- Rogers-Tanimoto
- Kulzinsky